# Bash: How can i send one mail instead of multiple mails

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting, mutt

I am learning shell scripting and i was stuck at sending an email.
here in below code i am using conditions to check the files size if it is greater than 0 bytes then send an email.

```
if [ -s file1 ]
      printf "%s" "this is file1" | /usr/bin/mutt -s "test file" "ssunkara@mail.com" 

fi

if [ -s file2 ]
      printf "%s" "this is file2" | /usr/bin/mutt -s "test file" "ssunkara@mail.com" 

fi
if [ -s file3 ]
      printf "%s" "this is file3" | /usr/bin/mutt -s "test file" "ssunkara@mail.com" 

fi
```

as we can see i am using same code `/usr/bin/mutt -s "test file" "ssunkara@mail.com"` three times which i feel not a good coding.
Is there any way that i can send the only one email with all the three messages in it.

ex: if all the three files are greater than zero bytes, i will receive 3 mails seperatly but instead i am looking to get only one mail like below.

```
this is file1
this is file2
this is file3
```

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [bash for loops](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-for-loop/) and [cat](https://www.howtogeek.com/278599/how-to-combine-text-files-using-the-cat-command-in-linux/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `>>` redirect to generate a temporary file first, then send the file:

```
out=$(mktemp /tmp/message.XXXXXXXX)
printf "%s" "this is file1" >> "$out"
printf "%s" "this is file2" >> "$out"
cat "$out" | mutt -s "test file" test@example.com
rm "$out"
```

Alternatively, it is possible to group multiple commands using `{ ...; }` and pipe all of their output into the same process:

```
{
    if [ -s file1 ]
        printf "%s" "this is file1"
    fi
    if [ -s file2 ]
        printf "%s" "this is file2"
    fi
    if [ -s file3 ]
        printf "%s" "this is file3"
    fi
} | mutt -s "test file" test@example.com
```

Don't forget you can apply the `|` pipe to compound commands as well, e.g. the entire `if...fi` or `for..in...done` can be piped to another command:

```
for fname in file{1..3}; do
    if [ -s "$fname" ]; then
        printf "%s" "this is $fname"
    fi
done | mutt -s "test file" test@example.com
```